# Change state of React component from old external Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, legacy

How can I change the state of a React component from my old legacy jQuery soup
code?

I have a component like this:

```
var AComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { ids: [] }
  },
  render: function() {
    ...
  },
  onButtonClick: function() {
    ids.splice(…); // remove the last id
  }
});
```

When something special happens in the old jQuery soup code, I'd like to
push an id to `AComponent.state.ids`. How can I do that?

One "obvious" solution is an anti-pattern; here it is:

```
var componentInstance = AComtonent({});
React.renderComponent(componentInstance, document.getElementById(...));

// Somewhere else, in the jQuery soup. Something special happens:
componentIntance.state.ids.push(1234);
componentIntance.setState(componentInstance.state);
```

This is an antipattern, according to [this email from a Facebook
developer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/reactjs/pyUZBRWcHB4/4gnxlVQZF0MJ),
because he writes that `componentInstance` might be destroyed by React.

Comment: I think by design a state mutation is supposed to be internal, so if you want to change it from outside, you should use a props. Which means splitting your component in two in your case. IE: moving your state to something encompassing your jquery soup trigger and thus solving your problem.

Comment: @plus Good to know that state mutation should be internal only. I didn't understand what you mean with *"encompassing your jquery soup trigger"* — did you mean that the state should be placed outside the component and I'd pass state mutators as props to the component? (As in kulesa's answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make the component stateless. Store the `ids` array outside of your component and pass it as a prop with functions that will modify the array. See example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ohvco4o2/5/