# Update React component with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update a React component from an external basic javascript code.
I understood that the only way to do this is to use props instead of states.
I tried to follow an example given in an old answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26035935/10469201) but I can't make it work.
Also, is it a bad practice to frequently update a component this way ? Or is there another way ?

**EDIT :** Code I've tried:

index.html:

```
<div id="root"></div>
<button id='changeprop'>change name</button>
```

index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App name="default name"/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const $ = window.$;

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.name = props.name;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                name : {this.name}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

var Wrapper = function(name, el) {
  var newName = name;
  function update() {
    return ReactDOM.render(<App name={newName}/>, el)
  }
  return {
    update: update
  }
}

var newName = "new name";
var wrapper = Wrapper(newName, document.getElementById('root'));

$('#changeprop').on('click', function(){ wrapper.update(); });
```

On button click, I re-render the component but the name displayed is still "default name" when I'd like it to display "new name"

Comment: Please share the relevant code you tried and not working

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Import js code, choose a lifecycle and props and try update it. Detailed lifecycle and examples here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method [forceUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) with your component instance despite it's not recommended to use it.

You can also define a stateful component and use the component method `setState` to re-render your component with different data

Here is an [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pyyndp)

Comment: Indeed the forceUpdate works and with your example the component state is changed from external code, but it's because the render() method does change it. I tried passing a props to componentInstance but with no success. Is there a way to pass parameter to the render method?

Comment: I updated my example, as `props` are readonly, you need to use `setState` if you want to change data from the outside

Comment: Thanks, your updated example does the trick! I didn't know you could use setState like that